# cpu usage of a code block in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get Powershell to give me the average CPU usage of a code block, but can't figure out what wmi class to use.

This only gives me the current usage:

> Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property
>   LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average

Answer (score 0):

The class used will return data on CPU level. Try looking at [process level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) to get more fine-grained numbers.

The member `UserModeTime` contains the process' CPU time usage. A simple way to convert it into more readable values is to use `TimeSpan` like so, `[TimeSpan]::FromMilliseconds()`

Comment: I'm trying to get average CPU load percentage of different blocks inside a script. like: Measure-Command -Expression {some code}